# Spring Boot 1.4: SpringBootTest and Apache Axis2 issues

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

**[SOLVED]**

I am using Spring Boot 1.4 and could run the test class without any problem.  After added Apache Axis2 into the pom.xml and the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRestTemplate': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequest
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
    public class ApplicationTests {

        @Test
        public void contextLoads() {
        }

    }
```

I assume the problem is with the `Httpclient` and I add `<exclusion>` to `axis2-transport-http` in pom.xml and the error does not occur anymore.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${axis2.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The question here is - I want to know the reason of the error and why adding exclusion solved the problem since I am not sure whether it's the real solution or not.

**EDIT:**
The real problem was the maven cache and it works after cleaning the local repository. Thank to Andy for the solution.

Comment: Spring Boot will try to use `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` if it's on the classpath. It's in `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`. `org.apache.http.HttpRequest` is part of `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore` which is a dependency of `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`. Unless you have so mismanaged versions or some exclusions elsewhere, `HttpClient` shouldn't be on the classpath without `HttpRequest` also being there. Can you share the rest of your pom and the output from `mvn dependency:tree` please?

Comment: Hi Andy! my pom.xml is here. https://gist.github.com/yehtoo/fa3e472f659b115e3d4fd6e8fd6c670c
and dependency tree is here. https://gist.github.com/yehtoo/8e410cfd7586ba74b9bb94c1fd861a18

Comment: Hi Andy. I also created a new project on Spring Initializr, and after I added the HttpClient dependency to its pom.xml, running JUnit test gave same errors.

Comment: It works for me with the same dependencies. I'd guess that Maven has cached a corrupted jar in its cache. Try clearing out the cache to force it to download your dependencies again.

Comment: thank you so much, Andy. it works after removing those jars from local repository and downloading them again. thanks . .  you save my day.